# Energy needed for Superman to take off and fly at the speed of sound

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, estimation

I just watched "Man of Steel", and I'm wondering if my logic is correct.

Let's assume Superman is 80 kg. The energy required to take off from the rest to reach the speed of sound in air (if I neglect the drag) is:

$E_k = 0.5mv^2$ = $0.5\cdot80\cdot340^2$ = $4\times10^6 \ J$.

Also add the potential energy at height $h$, $E_p=mgh = 784h \approx 0.2\times10^6 \ J$ (Let's assume at $h = 300 \ m$)

Total energy is roughly $4.8\times10^6 \ J.$

Superman gains his energy from the sun. Assume solar flux at Earth's surface is $1340 \  W/m^2$ (max), and Superman's surface area is roughly $2 \ m^2$ (calculated using Du Bois formula). Then the maximum energy that can be absorbed by Superman on Earth is $2\cdot1340 = 2680 \ J$ per second. (Solar flux is much less on the surface, but here I used this value anyway.)

Then to take off, he needs to wait:

$(4.8\times10^6)/2680 \approx 1791 \ s \approx 29.9 \min.$

It doesn't seem correct. Please correct me if I am wrong. (This is close to the perfect situation, which neglects many factors that could make the charging time longer. This also assumes his tank is empty. Thanks for pointing it out. If you are interested, please feel free to write down a more realistic estimation.)

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I just thought the movie must have some kind of science back up, it shouldn't have made a model where superman needs 30min charge to take off.

Comment: I think energy requirements shouldn't be your first worry when it comes to realism and superman. It's all just 'comic-book-physics'.

Comment: Yes I agree, but is this the correct way of looking at this "problem"?

Comment: As far as I can tell without having seen the movie, yes. Although this is only the very best perfect situation. The atmosphere will absorb some sunlight, reducing solar flux, and not all $2 \space m^2$ of super man's body will be absorbing sunlight. And that's not even considering the efficiency of super man's 'propulsion system'.

Comment: Also, the energy requirements for actually sustaining that speed are huge, considering that his cape doesn't really help to reduce drag.

Comment: Why do you feel he doesn't store solar energy? So he doesn't need to wait 30 minutes to take off?

Comment: I am assuming his tank is empty. Of course if you include the energy he stored in 20 years (assuming his storage is perfect, no loss) Then he can fly for about 7 days. Or take off about 20,000 times.

Comment: But you know his consumption is much faster than his charging. Unless he goes to the Sun for a week of holiday and come back to find the Earth is gone...

Comment: Hahahaha plus never know how much energy the Krypton star gave him when he was a baby. :P @KyleKanos ;)

Comment: Note though that to sustain the speed he just has to overcome the drag forces, which will probably be a lot less than the energy necessary to accelerate. This could be calculate given pressure drag (well superman doesn't have a perfect droplet form) - skin drag (even those high aerodynamic suits from ice skaters produce a lot of drag) and last but not least wave drag (depends on the length of superman's arm during flight a lot :P). Might actually make an interesting what-if question for xkcd ><

Comment: haha fair enough..but I thought Kyrpton star are much dimmer (less luminosity) compared to the Sun...and btw, energy sustaining that flight speed is just the work done against the drag right..?

Comment: Oh, yes. I had forgotten. Krypton's sun is older and red. Which gives out less energy :P

Comment: ...and that $1340\ W/m^2$ figure is the flux at the top of the atmosphere. Significantly less reaches the surface. There is a reason you don't see solar powered fighter jets.

Comment: What makes you think he has to spend this energy immediately. He'll be charging during flight too. That will lay off a few minutes from the charging period.

Comment: @MichaelBrown You are absolutely correct, which is why I indicated in the question that this is close to a perfect situation and if you consider it in detail, it will just make the charging time longer.

Comment: @udiboy Yeah I agree, but I mean he reaches the speed of sound with in seconds. So during this couple of second, the energy he can charge is not significant compared to his consumption. In fact it's probably less than 0.1% percent of his energy consumption....so 29.85 becomes 29.82 min...which may lead to saving Lois' life.

Comment: Great! I think the approximations are valid and the calculation is sound. At the speed of sound, I expect drag forces to be significant, though. Accelerating the car, the gas use goes up to 30- 35 l/100km, while driving constantly, it is at 6-7 l/100km. This is a mere factor of 5 and will get worse at higher speeds...

Comment: Hi Jin. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Although irrelevant, you will find this interesting : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartoon_physics

Comment: This is ka-el under the influence of a yellow star, nothing about solar energy. After all, he has the power at night and underground. Obviously something else is going on. He directly taps the luminiferous aether or has a metabolic extension into a degenerate dimension that connects him to the solar core, or maybe the Yellow Energy astronomers and electronicists have been looking for.

Comment: You know he doesn't only get his energy from the Sun. He also eats food. That probably is where he draws his energy from when the "tanks are empty". Plus his body, like yours or mine, can probably go into starvation mode. We can still jump and run even after several days without eating because our bodies can do things like cannibalize themselves for energy. I assume him being low on solar fuel is akin to us being really hungry

Comment: Oh my God. And in Star Wars, there are superluminal communications! Those are fiction movies, and pretty good ones I must say. You haven't tried figuring out where the energy comes from when Harry Potter uses his wand, have you? P.S. maybe superman uses some kind of a battery: he absorbs solar energy and then uses it when he needs to.

Comment: From your first two statements you have $4.0 + 0.2 = 4.8$ ????

Comment: FWIW, Superman's mass is [107 kg](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_%28Clark_Kent%29).

Comment: I find it amazing that a significant minority of physics students that I teach at the high school level are influenced by comic book heros.  Some of my students have told me that it is possible to do Iron Man stunts if you are wearing his suit!  It would be nice if students would realize that Hollywood physics is pure fantasy and nothing more.  In other words, it's MUCH MORE DIFFICULT to teach students to unlearn a mis-concept than it is to teach the proper concept to a totally unbiased student.

Comment: @Jim To expand on your suggestion that he could derive the necessary energy from food instead of sunlight, 4.8×10^6 joules is equivalent to 1147 kcal (food calories), so as long as he can have a large burger, fries, and maybe a milkshake he would be good to go for a flight. There are strongman competitors and other athletes that eat around 10,000 calories a day, so if Superman consumed similar amounts of food then his energy output starts to seem plausible.

Answer (score 1):

actually I'm only a high school student but i hope i can help.

first of all, we should specify how we want the superman to fly. i assume here that it takes off straight upward from earth and then it flies directly parallel to earth's surface.(i have assumed that earth is a plane not a sphere.)
 
 
for the take off, we need to dominate earth's gravity. the energy we need is the same as the difference of the gravitational potential energy of the 2 points. (1 on the surface of the earth and the other on the appropriate height, what you assumed to be *300 m* ) so we have:
$ E=mgh$ 
 $E= 80* 9.8* 300=2.35*10^5 J$ 
 now super man is at the desired height and the only thing we need is to give it a speed of sound. the energy needed is kinetic energy given by:
 
 $k=1/2 *m *v^2$
 $k=1/2* 80* 340^2 = 4.62* 10^6 J$ 
 
 the total energy is :
 $E_t=48.55*10^5 J$ 
till here all your calculations were right. but, the energy that super man absorbs produce a pressure on him and so a force.the force direction is opposite to sun, it means toward earth! so it can't directly use sun's energy to accelerate away from earth or to reach the speed of sound at a direction perpendicular to the radiation.
 if we assume super man has some "thing" that can convert radiative energy to mechanical energy (for example by using solar pills,...) then your calculation is right! but it even takes less time for superman to leave earth. because at first it doesn't need to have the hole energy! i think we should calculate the difference of potential energy by unit time. and compare it with the energy received at his body's area. if the energy recieved is larger than the energy required, so it can fly. and otherwise, not.

Answer (score -5):

There is a much bigger problem given conservation of linear momentum:  When Superman zooms thisaway, what zooms in opposition thataway?  Remarkably, the *Book of Mormon* seems to address this issue.  David O. McKay, 1963; softcover edition published 1976; left side color plate facing p. 397.  This is not the Son of Krypton's solution.